# array with same index changed without being reassigned

Tags: c++, arrays, loops

I am having trouble with this program. What it is intended to do is read a list of words, then take input for how long the word is, from the words of this length, count up the total of all the letters in them, sort them by highest frequency, and ask the user for the one with the highest frequency. Before it asks, it checks if that letter has already been asked be looping though the array prevguess. My problem is that, if I enter that 'yesletter' is true, the content of this array gets changed at the point after the inline comment "problem occurs here". The value of q within this test loop I put in doesn't change, but the value itself changes.

I know that the loop in main is infinite right now, but the program is not finished.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int i(0),n(0),counter(0),limit(0),length,mastercount(0);
int acount(0),bcount(0),ccount(0),dcount(0),ecount(0),fcount(0),gcount(0),hcount(0);
int icount(0),jcount(0),kcount(0),lcount(0),mcount(0),ncount(0),ocount(0),pcount(0);
int qcount(0),rcount(0),scount(0),tcount(0),ucount(0),vcount(0),wcount(0),xcount(0),ycount(0),zcount(0);
int letters[2][26];
char prevguess[26];
char words[60000][30];


void initarray() {

    int len(0);
    string line;
    char temp;

    ifstream wordlist ("words.txt");

    if (wordlist.is_open())
    {
        while (wordlist.good())
        {
            getline (wordlist,line);
            len=line.length();

            for (n=0;n<30;n++)
            {
                if (n<len){
                    temp=line.at(n);
                    words[i][n]=temp;
                }
                else{
                    words[i][n]='*';
                }
            }

            i++;
            counter++;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"file not opened";
    }
    wordlist.close();
}

void selectlength()
{
    int x(0),y(0);
    bool shorter(false),longer(false);

    cout <<"length of word"<<endl;
    cin >> length;

    limit=counter;
    counter=0;

    for (i=0;i<limit;i++){

        shorter=false;
        longer=false;

        for (n=0;n<length;n++){
            if (words[i][n]=='*')
            {
                shorter=true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (words[i][length] != '*')
        {
            longer=true;
        }

        if (!longer && !shorter)
        {
                n=0;
                for (y=0;y<30;y++)
                {
                    if (n<length){
                        words[x][y]=words[i][n];
                        n++;
                    }
                    else{
                        words[x][y]='*';
                    }
                }
                x++;
                counter++;

        }

    }
}

void mostletters(){
    char temp;

    for (i=0;i<counter;i++){
        for (n=0;n<=length;n++){

            temp=words[i][n];
            switch (temp){
                case 'a':
                    acount++;
                    break;
                case 'b':
                    bcount++;
                    break;
                case 'c':
                    ccount++;
                    break;
                case 'd':
                    dcount++;
                    break;
                case 'e':
                    ecount++;
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    fcount++;
                    break;
                case 'g':
                    gcount++;
                    break;
                case 'h':
                    hcount++;
                    break;
                case 'i':
                    icount++;
                    break;
                case 'j':
                    jcount++;
                    break;
                case 'k':
                    kcount++;
                    break;
                case 'l':
                    lcount++;
                    break;
                case 'm':
                    mcount++;
                    break;
                case 'n':
                    ncount++;
                    break;
                case 'o':
                    ocount++;
                    break;
                case 'p':
                    pcount++;
                    break;
                case 'q':
                    qcount++;
                    break;
                case 'r':
                    rcount++;
                    break;
                case 's':
                    scount++;
                    break;
                case 't':
                    tcount++;
                    break;
                case 'u':
                    ucount++;
                    break;
                case 'v':
                    vcount++;
                    break;
                case 'w':
                    wcount++;
                    break;
                case 'x':
                    xcount++;
                    break;
                case 'y':
                    ycount++;
                    break;
                case 'z':
                    zcount++;
                    break;

            }
        }
    }
}

void guessmost(){
    int x,y,temp,temp2,q;

    for (x=0;x<26;x++){

        letters[0][x]=x;

        switch (x){
            case 0:
                letters[1][x]=acount;
                break;
        case 1:
            letters[1][x]=bcount;
            break;
        case 2:
            letters[1][x]=ccount;
            break;
        case 3:
            letters[1][x]=dcount;
            break;
        case 4:
            letters[1][x]=ecount;
            break;
        case 5:
            letters[1][x]=fcount;
            break;
        case 6:
            letters[1][x]=gcount;
            break;
        case 7:
            letters[1][x]=hcount;
            break;
        case 8:
            letters[1][x]=icount;
            break;
        case 9:
            letters[1][x]=jcount;
            break;
        case 10:
            letters[1][x]=kcount;
            break;
        case 11:
            letters[1][x]=lcount;
            break;
        case 12:
            letters[1][x]=mcount;
            break;
        case 13:
            letters[1][x]=ncount;
            break;
        case 14:
            letters[1][x]=ocount;
            break;
        case 15:
            letters[1][x]=pcount;
            break;
        case 16:
            letters[1][x]=qcount;
            break;
        case 17:
            letters[1][x]=rcount;
            break;
        case 18:
            letters[1][x]=scount;
            break;
        case 19:
            letters[1][x]=tcount;
            break;
        case 20:
            letters[1][x]=ucount;
            break;
        case 21:
            letters[1][x]=vcount;
            break;
        case 22:
            letters[1][x]=wcount;
            break;
        case 23:
            letters[1][x]=xcount;
            break;
        case 24:
            letters[1][x]=ycount;
            break;
        case 25:
            letters[1][x]=zcount;
            break;
        }
    }


    for (y=0;y<26;y++){



        //problem occurs here (I think)

        for (q=mastercount-1;q>=0;q--){
                    cout<<"for array index:"<<q;
                    cout << " the value of prevguess is "<<prevguess[q]<<endl;
        }





        for (x=26;x>=1;x--){
            if (letters[1][x]>letters[1][x-1])
            {
                temp=letters[1][x-1];
                letters[1][x-1]=letters[1][x];
                letters[1][x]=temp;

                temp2=letters[0][x-1];
                letters[0][x-1]=letters[0][x];
                letters[0][x]=temp2;
            }
        }

    }
}

void letterguess(){
    int x(0),z;
    char guess;
    bool goodletter(false),yesletter(false),alreadyguess(false);

    while (!goodletter){

        guess=letters[0][x]+97;

        if (mastercount==0){
            alreadyguess=false;
        }
        else{
            for (z=mastercount-1;z>=0;z--){
                if (guess==prevguess[z]){
                    alreadyguess=true;
                }
            }
        }

        if (!alreadyguess){
            cout<<"is your letter "<< guess<<endl;
            cin >> yesletter;
            prevguess[mastercount]=guess;
        }

        if (yesletter && !alreadyguess){
            goodletter=true;
        }
        else {
            cout<<"wrong"<<endl;
            x++;
        }

        mastercount++;

        if (mastercount>26){
                    break;
                }
    }

}

int main() {
    bool found(false);
    initarray();
    selectlength();
    while (!found){
        mostletters();
        guessmost();
        letterguess();
        if (mastercount>26){
            break;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Each letter (char) has a unique ascii value, you would be better off converting your letters to an int containing the ascii value and use an array to reference each letter count instead of defining lots of variables and a giant switch statement. I'd also look at putting some debug code into your program using #ifdef DEBUG and or assert statements. Someone might give you the answer but you're better off with the tools.

Comment: futher to above: declare int letter[26];

replace mostletters() switch with:
int temp = (int) words[i][n]-97;
if(temp>=0 and temp <26) letter[temp]++;

replace guessmost() switch with;
letters[1][x] = letter[x];

Comment: You should really narrow the problem down. I'm not even sure you're asking a question.

Comment: @user1489736 Great idea! That cuts down a lot of unnecessary code, and it works perfectly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problems start a bit lower than your comment.

```
for (x=26;x>=1;x--){
       if (letters[1][x]>letters[1][x-1])
```

When `x` is 26, `letters[1][x]` will be out of range.

Comment: Wow that was right, thanks. But if you could help me understand why it was broken in the first place, that would be great. The array just above the code you mentioned returns different values, even though the starting value of q is always the same, and the array it outputs is not accessed until these loops have finished. Why is that? Thanks again!

Comment: When you try to access more elements that there is in an array, you get random values (at best). If you write outside an array, that can affect other variables and mess everything up. We don't know *what* can happen later.